# How to use Swagger @ApiOperation annotation in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, swagger, springfox-boot-starter

How to convert the following Swagger annotations from Java to Kotlin?

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Create a person", notes = "API login ", extensions = {
@Extension(properties = { @ExtensionProperty(name = "x-42c-no-authentication", value = "true") })
})
```